# Suspend mode reset my configuration to internal microphone instead of keeping usb microphone as default

Tags: pm-utils

Suspend mode reset my configuration to internal microphone instead of keeping usb microphone as default.

I always have to manually change it back in the sounds parameters.

Reboot is ok : keeps the usb microphone as default.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem :

### A)

> 1. Create a file `/etc/pm/power.d/10_alsa-restart`.
> 2. Edit the file add the following:
>
>    ```
>    #!/bin/sh
>    /sbin/alsa force-reload
>    ```
>
> 3) Save the file and make it executable.

<sup>Source: http://daybydaylinux.blogspot.ca/2011/09/alsa-no-sound-after-suspend-in-lucid.html</sup>

### B)

Also, in the file "etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf", I added:

```
options snd-hda-intel=1
options snd-usb-audio=0
```

And I commented all `options` lines after this one:

```
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
```

I found the name of devices and index with:

```
cat /proc/asound/modules
```

### C)

Also, in the file `etc/pulse/default.pa`, I added this (uncommenting the last line and replacing `source` with the name of my device):

```
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_0821_3961BAE0-00-U0x46d0x821.iec958-stereo
```

I had found the name of my device with:

```
pacmd list-sources
```

Comment: ERRATUM :B)
options snd-hda-intel index=1
options snd-usb-audio index=0